# React-scroll navigate within the same page (dropdown menu)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-scroll

I am trying to implement the navigation on my portfolio app using `react-scroll`, and it works fine until screen width changes and dropdown menu appears, since all of my components are rendered on the same page. It's pretty easy implementing `react-router` when I have multipage app, but this one really got me.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import React from 'react';
import { faBars, faCircleXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import "./Navbar.css";
import {Link} from 'react-scroll';

function Navbar() {
    const navRef = useRef();

    const showNavbar = () => {
        navRef.current.classList.toggle(
            "responsive_nav"
        );
    };

    return (
        <header>
            <nav ref={navRef}>  
                <Link to="home" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500}>Home</Link>
                <Link to="about" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500}>About me</Link>
                <Link to="mywork" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500}>My Work</Link>
                <Link to="contact" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-150} duration={500}>Contact</Link>
                <button
                    className="nav-btn nav-close-btn"
                    onClick={showNavbar}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleXmark} style={{color: "#FFB30D",}} />
                </button>
            </nav>
            <button
                className="nav-btn nav-open"
                onClick={showNavbar}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} style={{color: "#FFB30D",}}/>
            </button>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

```
import './App.css'
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar.jsx";
import Home from "./Components/Home.jsx";
import AboutMe from "./Components/AboutMe.jsx";
import MyWork from './Components/MyWork.jsx';
import Footer from './Components/Footer.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Home />
      <AboutMe />
      <MyWork />
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter> 
  );
}

export default App
```

Once I click on the link in the dropdown menu, it does scroll to the chosen section, but the dropdown menu doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once I click on the link in the dropdown menu, it does scroll to the
> chosen section, but the dropdown menu doesn't disappear.

Add an `onClick` handler that calls `showNavbar` to the links so when they are clicked on to scroll to the specific section they can also close the menu. I suggest also renaming `showNavbar` to something more accurate, like `toggleNavbar` since that is really what it does.

```
function Navbar() {
  const navRef = useRef();

  const toggleNavbar = () => {
    navRef.current.classList.toggle(
      "responsive_nav"
    );
  };

  const linkProps = {
    onClick: toggleNavbar, // <-- add onClick handler
    spy: true,
    smooth: true,
    offset: -100,
    duration: 500,
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <nav ref={navRef}>  
        <Link to="home" {...linkProps}>Home</Link>
        <Link to="about" {...linkProps}>About me</Link>
        <Link to="mywork" {...linkProps}>My Work</Link>
        <Link to="contact" {...linkProps}>Contact</Link>
        <button
          className="nav-btn nav-close-btn"
          onClick={toggleNavbar}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleXmark} style={{ color: "#FFB30D" }} 
 />
        </button>
      </nav>
      <button
        className="nav-btn nav-open"
        onClick={toggleNavbar}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} style={{ color: "#FFB30D" }} />
      </button>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: And I tried adding an onClick with a ton of code. No wonder it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that if I click some of the links while on full width and then minimize, dropdown opens up. I guess it happens because the onClick is now triggering that, but I'm not sure how to stop it.

Comment: @Igor Can you clarify what you mean by "and then minimize"? The code you are using is directly manipulating the DOM with `navRef.current.classList.toggle("responsive_nav");`, which is generally considered a React anti-pattern. It would probably be better to use a local `isOpen` state, set the state in the click handler, and then conditionally apply the `"responsice_nav"` CSS `className` prop value. Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh, I understand. I'll fix that right away. And just to clarify my question: if I click an about me link for example, while navbar being displayed in full width, and then minimize the browser after it (smart phone width for example) it automatically opens up the dropdown nav. Which didn't happen before adding the onClick.

Comment: @Igor That's because the current code is "blindly" just toggling the the class on the element, regardless of its current open/close status. When you have the larger screen and click the links, they toggle it when they don't need to, then when the screen is resized small enough to display the nav, boom, it's displayed. In other words, you want the "open menu" button to set the class on the nav, and you want the "close button" and all the links to remove it.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to thank you for pointing out the wrongs in my navbar.  Made me learn and do the proper way, and it works well. Thanks!